# open friends request when user clicks allow in Facebook connect

Tags: facebook, multi-friend-selector

I allow users to use facebook connect to login to facebook and then give permission to my app.

When they click allow I want the multi-friend's selector to open so they can invite friend's to the site.  I need the permissions dialoge first so I can get the user_id's of the users the person invited.

Is there a way to open the multi-friend's selector when the user clicks allow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi when the user aunthenticate your application, it logins to your site, You can capture the event of login and can send him to any other url where you can put friend selector.

```
 FB.Event.subscribe("auth.login", function(response) {
  //send to some url(file) and put there friend selector
  });
```